# Angular 6 DecoupledEditor Not showing page preview like in demo

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I want to use the document viewer from ckeditor. It looks like a normal ckeditor, i want the version with the page.

It looks like this:
[original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tQ8r.png)

And in my app it looks like this:
[my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5mGH.png)

I installed CKeditor with following:

```
npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular    
npm i @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document
```

And used in HTML:

```
<ckeditor [editor]="Editor" data="<p>Hello, world!</p>" (ready)="onReady($event)"></ckeditor>
```

And in Component:

```
import * as DecoupledEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document';



public Editor = DecoupledEditor;

  public onReady(editor) {
    editor.ui.view.editable.element.parentElement.insertBefore(
      editor.ui.view.toolbar.element,
      editor.ui.view.editable.element
    );

  }
```

Comment: You'll need some [additional styles](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/deep-dive/ui/document-editor.html#styles) to get the native text processor look and feel.

Comment: Ok that make sense. I was expecting to be ready to use. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need some additional styles to get the native text processor look and feel. – oleq